# Is there a way to speed up this Python script?

Tags: python, mysql, performance

I’m fairly new to Python. I can write scripts that function but I’d like to know if there’s anything I can do to speed this script up.

Any mistakes or unnecessary/repetitive actions?

Here are the stats for the last run:

Tracking Check: [Start: 2021-04-15-07:40:01 CST] [Finish: 2021-04-15-07:47:33 CST] [Inserted: 172] [Deleted: 1634] [players: 120] [Runtime: 0:07:32.203772]

I have 100,000+ players to go through so any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

```
# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/
import requests
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html
import datetime
import mysql.connector
import json
import time
from time import sleep

currentTime2 = datetime.datetime.now()
currentTimeTime2 = currentTime2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
cstTime = (currentTime2 - datetime.timedelta(hours=6))
cstTime2 = cstTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')

# PRINT START TIME
def startTime():
    print('Tracking Check: [Start: ' + str(cstTime2) + ' CST] ', end="", flush=True)

# Script Timer
start_time = time.time()

# MySQL Connection - Open
# clanTrackingDb = mysql.connector.connect(host="db_IP", user="db_user", passwd="db-pass", db="DB")

# API Token
token = 'token'

cursor = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
cursor2 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()

activeClans = 0
inactiveClans = 0
clansGained = 0
clansLost = 0
playersInserted = 0
recordsDeleted = 0
recordsInserted = 0
valuesDelete = []
valuesInsert = []
valuesUpdate = []

# Clan Check Query
getPlayerTagsQuery = (
    "SELECT * FROM `playerRiverRaceHistory_merge` WHERE dataMerged = 'No' LIMIT 120")

cursor.execute(getPlayerTagsQuery)

result = cursor.fetchall()

resultCount = cursor.rowcount

tags = [i[1] for i in result]

for tag in tags:
    cursor5 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()

    getPlayerMergeStatusQuery = ("SELECT * FROM playerRiverRaceHistory WHERE playerTag = '%s'" % (tag))
                
    cursor5.execute(getPlayerMergeStatusQuery)

    getPlayerMergeStatusResult = cursor5.fetchall()

    getPlayerMergeStatusRowCount = cursor5.rowcount

    # print(str(tag) + ' - ' + str(getRiverRaceHistoryRowCount))

    if (getPlayerMergeStatusRowCount == 0):

        dataMerged = 'Yes'

        cursor3 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
        updatePlayerMergeStatusQuery = ("UPDATE playerRiverRaceHistory_merge SET dataMerged = %s WHERE playerTag = %s")
        cursor3.execute(updatePlayerMergeStatusQuery, (dataMerged, tag))
        clanTrackingDb.commit()
        cursor3.close()

        #playersInserted = playersInserted + 1

    else:
        for x in getPlayerMergeStatusResult:
            db_playerTag = x[1]
            db_playerClanTag = x[3]
            db_playerClanName = x[4]
            db_warLeague = x[5]
            db_warDate = x[6]
            db_fameCollected = x[7]
            db_repairCollected = x[8]
            db_decksUsed = 0
            # print(str(db_playerTag) + ' - ' + str(db_warDate))

            cursor2 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
            checkHistory2Query = ("SELECT * FROM playerRiverRaceHistory2 WHERE playerTag = '%s' AND playerClanTag = '%s' AND warDate = '%s'" % (db_playerTag, db_playerClanTag, db_warDate))         
            cursor2.execute(checkHistory2Query)
            checkHistory2Result = cursor2.fetchall()
            checkHistory2ResultRowCount = cursor2.rowcount

            if(checkHistory2ResultRowCount == 0):
                #print("Already in DB")
                # deleteHistoryQuery = ("DELETE FROM playerRiverRaceHistory WHERE playerTag = '%s' AND playerClanTag = '%s' AND warDate = '%s'" % (db_playerTag, db_playerClanTag, db_warDate))
                # cursor4 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
                # cursor4.execute(deleteHistoryQuery)
                # clanTrackingDb.commit()
                # cursor4.close
                # #print("Record Deleted - 1")
                recordsDeleted = recordsDeleted + 1
                valuesDelete.append((db_playerTag, db_playerClanTag, db_warDate))
            else:
                #print("Not in DB")
                # insertHistory2Query = ("INSERT INTO playerRiverRaceHistory2 (playerTag, playerClanTag, playerClanName, warLeague, warDate, fameCollected, repairCollected, decksUsed) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
                # cursor4 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
                # cursor4.execute(insertHistory2Query, (db_playerTag, db_playerClanTag, db_playerClanName, db_warLeague, db_warDate, db_fameCollected, db_repairCollected, db_decksUsed))
                # clanTrackingDb.commit()
                # cursor4.close
                #print("Data Inserted")
                recordsInserted = recordsInserted + 1
                valuesInsert.append((db_playerTag, db_playerClanTag, db_playerClanName, db_warLeague, db_warDate, db_fameCollected, db_repairCollected, db_decksUsed))

                dataMerged = "Yes"
                # cursor3 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
                # updatePlayerMergeStatusQuery = ("UPDATE playerRiverRaceHistory_merge SET dataMerged = %s WHERE playerTag = %s")
                # cursor3.execute(updatePlayerMergeStatusQuery, (dataMerged, db_playerTag))
                # clanTrackingDb.commit()
                # cursor3.close()
                #print("Merge Status Updated")
                valuesUpdate.append((dataMerged, db_playerTag))

                # deleteHistoryQuery = ("DELETE FROM playerRiverRaceHistory WHERE playerTag = '%s' AND playerClanTag = '%s' AND warDate = '%s'" % (db_playerTag, db_playerClanTag, db_warDate))
                # cursor4 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
                # cursor4.execute(deleteHistoryQuery)
                # clanTrackingDb.commit()
                # cursor4.close
                #print("Record Deleted - 2")
                recordsDeleted = recordsDeleted + 1
                valuesDelete.append((db_playerTag, db_playerClanTag, db_warDate))

            cursor2.close()

    cursor5.close()

insertHistory2Query = ("INSERT INTO playerRiverRaceHistory2 (playerTag, playerClanTag, playerClanName, warLeague, warDate, fameCollected, repairCollected, decksUsed) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
cursor6 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
cursor6.executemany(insertHistory2Query, valuesInsert)
clanTrackingDb.commit()
cursor6.close()

updatePlayerMergeStatusQuery = ("UPDATE playerRiverRaceHistory_merge SET dataMerged = %s WHERE playerTag = %s")
cursor7 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
cursor7.executemany(updatePlayerMergeStatusQuery, valuesUpdate)
clanTrackingDb.commit()
cursor7.close()

deleteHistoryQuery = ("DELETE FROM playerRiverRaceHistory WHERE playerTag = '%s' AND playerClanTag = '%s' AND warDate = '%s'")
cursor8 = clanTrackingDb.cursor()
cursor8.executemany(deleteHistoryQuery, valuesDelete)
clanTrackingDb.commit()
cursor8.close()

# Log Print
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
currentTimeTime = currentTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
currentTime2 = (currentTime - datetime.timedelta(hours=5))
currentTime3 = currentTime2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')

scriptTime = time.time() - start_time
scriptTime2 = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=scriptTime))

startTime()
print('[Finish: ' + str(currentTime3) + ' CST] [Inserted: ' + str(recordsInserted) + '] [Deleted: ' + str(recordsDeleted) + '] [players: ' + str(resultCount) + '] [Runtime: ' + str(scriptTime2) + ']')

cursor.close()
cursor2.close()
clanTrackingDb.close()
```

Comment: This might be better suited to [codereview.se] but read their guidelines before posting

Comment: If it works and performs to your satisfaction and you have included enough comments  so that you know what it is doing when you read it five years from now then best to just leave it alone. If you are looking for a *wide-open* critique then do as @Sayse suggests.

Comment: Yeah, this is too broad for SO. My only observation is that your problem seems to be very data heavy, yet your code is very python heavy. You do not use the full power of sql. Like when you loop through the results of a select and do another select, then an update based on the previous queries, all handled within python. This could probably be done in a single update query in sql using joins.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know what the table is like.

Answer (score 0):

- It sounds like there are multiple rows for each `playerTag`.  But why have `dataMerged` on every row?  Perhaps there needs to be a separate `Players` table?
- `SET dataMerged` shows up at least 3 times -- make a subroutine.
- Some indexes that might help:

  ```
    INDEX(playerTag, playerClanTag, warDate)
    INDEX(dataMerged)
  ```